# Mac email client that doesn't upload my data to remote servers

Tags: osx, email, email-client

I'm looking for a pure client side only mac email client that's better than thunderbird / apple mail. I'm a little bit burnt by rumors of popular apps stealing your data. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Edit: Hopefully free but I will also accept paid apps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? What do you mean by "better than" - what exactly you have found lacking in the aforementioned tools like Apple built-in Mail or freeware Thunderbird clients? Thunderbird is very customizable and has thousands of productivity extensions available for free. Also your mention of "stealing data" is a very far stretch, as any decent e-mail client is checked by hundreds of advanced users and secuirty researchers to make sure that no data goes where they shouldn't.

Comment: @Artanis hi I find the thunderbird UI to be displeasing. Mail has several problems including randomly restarting when it shouldn't and being lacking in features in gneral. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/mail-app-keeps-popping-up-in-the-background-in-mac-os-mojave There is no fix according to the top answer. AFAIK most free mail apps scans your mail for data collection / ads. Let me know if any doesn't do that. I assumed most of the popular ones like airmail / spark / sparrow work like that.